# Error: [$injector:unpr] and [$injector:nomod] when using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular js. When i am using this code the error, "Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] occur

```
 angular.module('app1')
.provider('Post',function(){
 this.$get = ['$resource', function ($resource) {
 var Post = $resource('http'://localhost:7214/Admn/University.aspx?/api/post/:_id', {}, {
update: {
method: 'PUT'
}
})
return Post;
}];
});
angular.module('app1')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', 'Post', function ($scope,     $route, Post) {
$scope.post = new Post();
$scope.posts = new Post.query();
$scope.newPost = function () {
$scope.post = new Post();
$scope.editing = false;
}
```

and when i add 'ngRoute' in my module then this error occurs, "Error: [$injector:unpr] .The code for this error is

```
angular.module('app1',['ngRoute'])
.provider('Post',function(){
this.$get = ['$resource', function ($resource) {
var Post = $resource('http'://localhost:7214/Admn/University.aspx?/api/post/:_id', {}, {
update: {
method: 'PUT'
}
})
return Post;
}];
});
angular.module('app1','[ngRoute]')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', 'Post', function ($scope,     $route, Post) {
$scope.post = new Post();
$scope.posts = new Post.query();
$scope.newPost = function () {
$scope.post = new Post();
$scope.editing = false;
}
```

Here are files the i included in my project.

```
<script src="/Scripts/Jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-ng-grid.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7    /angular-    resource.min.js"> </script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Note: In code above i have used 'http:'then rest of link . this is because     stackoverflow was giving error of link. in my project i have use     the original pattern of linking.'http:/..../..'

Comment: You are declaring the module twice:
angular.module('app1','[ngRoute]'). The furthers calls should be angular.module('app1')

Comment: beacause one for controller and another for provider

Comment: If you put a second argument to angular.module function, you are declaring it.
In the second snippet there are two calls which declare a moudule with the same name.

Comment: my above problems solved when i follow your (@Michael) instructions but here is another problem arise  "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]" when i use 
 angular.module('app1','[ngRoute]')
     .provider('Post',function(){....}
and
angular.module('app1')
        .controller('MainCtrl', ['.....

Comment: This is the correct syntax: angular.module('app1',['ngRoute']). The second argument is an array of strings

Comment: when i use module('appp1',['ngRoute]). The error remains this [$injector:unpr]